# Spring Boot Websockets: Is there a way to make Other Users reload page

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-websocket

When something from a client is sent through the websocket I want the other clients to refresh the page but not the sender.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
  const socket = new SockJS("/stomp-endpoint");
  const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
    stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", (greeting) => {
      console.log("UPDATE" + greeting.body);
      window.location = "/"; //location.reload();
    });
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("move")).forEach((element) =>
      element.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        console.log("move");
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", {}, JSON.stringify({ name: "Tammie" }));
      })
    );
  });
});
```

This is my javascript code but this way every client that subscribes to the websocket reloads his page which is a problem because other methods won't be resolved on the sender site.

I tried to give a User an id and it kinda worked to only reload Client that have a different id but I'm not quite sure how to set different id in My Controller without it changing everytime the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend sending an event to the server with the `id` of the sending client or some specific information about sender. The server should have a mapping for the websocket connections to each client/user. I would iterate through this mapping and send an specific event to each client except the sending one (the id mustn't match). Whenever a client receives this specific event then it reloads the page.

But, first of all, think about it. Do you really need to reload the entire page? Sounds like you want to reload the page, because things have changed. Instead of reloading the page you could just tell the client what have changed, so that the event_listener updates only part of the dom.

Also I would recommend you to read about server sent events. They are way cheaper than websockets.